# Como exportar a multiples worksheets en un ETL usando Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2015

Estoy tratando de exportar un archivo excel con dos tabs o worksheets en un ETL usando Visual Studio. No encuentro nada en la web que me ayude. Les adjunto el Controlflow y el Dataflow. Gracias!
[image: Control Flow]

[image: Data Flow]

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error?